# TitlePageIndicator selected line footer to header

Tags: java, android

I'm using the TabPageIndicator from Jake Wharton
My question: Is there any way to transform the tab footer line in a "header line"?
I'm using the indicator below the ViewPager and it would be nice to have the "selected line" on the top of my tab title.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the component doesn't support this option, however, that footer is a image, so if you rotate vertically this image, it becomes a header! LOL!